# jquery ajax call with xml query not working. Need advice

Tags: jquery

I've written some code that is supposed to load an xml file via AJAX, parse a couple variables, and alert them to the screen.  It isn't working...  Can any guru's out there tell me what I've done wrong??

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("http://www.greenshipping.com/api/requestAccountSummary.php?UID=7ef364b35ca79b0497f391da7f6776ab", {}, function(xml) {
        $('result', xml).each(function(i) {
            num_shipments = $(this).find('num_shipments_offset').text();
            lbs_carbon = $(this).find('total_lbs_carbon_offset').text();
            alert("num_shipments:"+num_shipments+" lbs_carbon:"+lbs_carbon);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the xml being returned from the server.  What does 'not working' mean

Comment: Are you calling it from the same domain ? Cross domain ajax calls are not allowed. Is the response xml ? Is the success method called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code isn't also in the domain `http://www.greenshipping.com`, then you're being blocked on purpose. Cross-domain AJAX requests are banned unless the user has already granted special permission.

Comment: Bummer...  I guess I should have known that.  Thanks for your help.